# Import csv file which contains columns of different lengths --> How can I delete empty fields?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, csv-format

I have the following problem:
I want to import a csv file into Mathematica. I file as a lot of rows and columns, but the column lengths differ for certain rows.
2 columns always belong together, forming x,y values.

The import works fine, BUT the size of my csv "matrix" seems to be interpreted as: number of row * number of LONGEST column. I therefore get a lot of empty spaces {} in all columns that are shorter.

What I want to do in Mathematica is the following:
Import the file.
Rearrange the csv matrix such, that I get {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},....} values for different experiments.

My code looks as following:

```
imp=Import["filepath...csv"]
imp//Transpose
```

I am stuck there, because I get a lot of {{,},{,},{,},....} at the end of the shorter lists.
How can I remove them?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try `DeleteCases[imp,{,}]` or using a rule replacement `imp /. {,} -> Sequence[]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The DeleteCases solution works, but only if I type: DeleteCases[imp,{"",""}]. The second solution does not work. I have found it on another site, but even if I use {"",""} or only "", the solution does not work.

Comment: @Niki @Pickett Those empty entries might actually be just empty strings `""`, in which case the replacement could be even easier. Let me make a toy CSV file to play with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the InputForm of the List you get from Import, you will notice that all those "empty" entries are actually an empty string, i.e. `""`. You can then replace the string with an empty Sequence[], and the empty sequence will automatically be flattened out of the list.

I generated a .CSV file with your pattern of pairs of columns of different lengths, then imported it

```
data = Import["sample.csv"]

(*Out:
{{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},
{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},{1,1,2,2,3,3,,},
{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,3,3,,},
{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,3,3,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},
{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,},{1,1,,,,,,}}
*)
```

If you check the `InputForm` for that expression, you will see a lot of the following:

```
...  List[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, "", ""],  List[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, "", ""], ...
```

We can then do the replacement:

```
cleaneddata = data /. "" -> Sequence[];
cleaneddata // TableForm

(*
{{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4},
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3},
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3},
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, 
{1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1},
{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
*)
```

You should then be able to extract pairs of columns from this data set using `[[ ]]`, etc.